# Simple way to select chosen option in <select> from the value given by $_POST?

Tags: php, html, post, html-select

How can i add the `selected="selected"` bit to the option in an HTML `<select>` input from the sent `$_POST` data without an if statement within each option?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058824/keep-a-select-box-selected-after-submit/2058868#2058868

Comment: @BalusC: Not really since the actual question is how to prevent the requirement of an if statement within each option.

Comment: @tarnfeld: Why did you accepted an answer with an if statement for each option, even though you asked for a solution 'without an if statement within each option'?

Comment: @Veger: I didn't use an if statement within each option.

Comment: `($selected == $value ? ' selected' : '')` is an (inline) if statement... In my answer below there is no if statement used (except to check if $_POST was set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$options = array(1 => 'Banana', 2 => 'Apple');

foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
    echo '<option value=""';
    if ($key == $_POST['fruit']) echo ' selected="selected"';
    echo '>'.$value.'</option>';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Programatically, you could do it like this:

```
$optionNames = array('This', 'Is', 'A', 'Test');
echo '<select id="testselect" name="testselect">';
foreach($optionNames as $currentOption) {
    echo '<option value="'.$currentOption.'"';
    echo $_POST['testselect'] == $currentOption ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    echo '>'.$currentOption.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Must confess I don't have a dev box up at the moment to test the above code, but it should be OK. (Apologies if not.) :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose using an if statement for each option is most efficient.

But you can create an array containing empty strings except for the location of the option you want to select in order to eliminate the if statement.

```
$options = array(1 => 'Banana', 2 => 'Apple', 3 => 'Orange');
$selected_options = array_fill(1, sizeof($options), "");
if(array_key_exists($_POST['fruit'], $options))
    $selected_options[$_POST['fruit']] = " selected=\"selected\"";

echo '<select id="fruit" name="fruit">';
foreach($options as $optionId => $optionText)
    echo '<option value="'.$optionId.'"'.$selected_options[$optionId].'>'.$optionText.'</option>';
echo '</select>';
```