# javascript keep a selected value from a list after form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, selected

i have a little form with a select list, and i am submitting the form every time i select an item. the problem is that, after selecting a value and submitting the form, the selected item doesn't remain selected. Is there any method to keep the selected item selected in the list, after the form submit? (using javascript for example)?

```
<form name="order_of_products_by_values" id="order_of_products_by_values" method="post" action="">
<select id="order_of_products_by_values" name="order_of_products_by_values"  onChange="this.form.submit();">   
<option value=1 >Pret crescator</option>
<option value=2 >Pret descrescator</option>
<option value=3 >Test</option>
<option value=4 >Test</option>
</select>
</form>
```

thank you!

Comment: If you're using any sort of server-side HTML generation, the easiest thing to do would be to set that option as selected in the markup that gets sent back. There _are_ strictly client-side ways of getting this done, though (local storage, cookies, etc.). More to the point, though: **why are you submitting the form every time the `<select>` changes**?

Comment: Add some php/asp to preserve the selected value

Comment: Why do your `form` and `select` elements have the same `id` and the same `name`? No wonder you are having trouble...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use a server side solution, you could set a cookie after the onchange-Event fires and submit the form. For informations about javascript cookies, take a look at the following site: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: so, you advise me that i would better use a server side solution, so that i should set a php variable like $selected and then verify each time which value is selected, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058824/keep-a-select-box-selected-after-submit

Comment: Yes. I personally prefer the server side solution since every client will get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use AJAX? If you use jQuery you can submit the form and the select list wont be altered after selection.

```
jQuery('#order_of_products_by_values').change(function() { 

    jQuery.post('ajax/test.php', jQuery("#order_of_products_by_values_FORM").serialize());

});
```

Also, notice I changed the ID of the form since it is the same ID as the select list which can cause conflicts.

The serialize function will serialize the form and send it to the test.php script where it can be used as usual. Ex:

```
$select = $_POST['order_of_products_by_values'];
```