# Wanting to keep selected html option after submitting and page reload

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have seen a few similar posts, but nothing that I could find for Rails. 
My question is similar to: [Keep a Select Box Selected after Submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058824/keep-a-select-box-selected-after-submit) and the answer is okay for what I want to do except for being PHP.

All I want to do is after the user selects the filter options and reloads the last selected option stays selected instead of going to the default which is all at the moment. I am using Rails and I have Ajax and jQuery as viable options to do this. Right now the page reload and filtering all works but I just want the selected option to stay selected after the reload. Was looking to reload just the portion of my table with the info with Ajax at first but I think that would be over my head.

My Table with options (yeah I know it's messy I am new to web applications so if there are any unrelated suggestions I'm open):

```
<html>
<table class= "table table-bordered"%>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Status:</th>
      <th>Clec ID:</th>
      <th>Task ID:</th>
      <th>Task Type:</th>
      <th>Hostname:</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
         <form action="/task_queues" method="GET"> 
            <td>
                <select name="by_status">
                  <option value="">All</option>
                  <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                  <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                  <option value="Failed">Failed</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="by_clecid">
                  <option value="">All</option>
                  <% @clecids.each do |clecid| %><option value="<%= clecid %>"><%= clecid %></option><% end %> 
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="by_taskid">
                  <option value="">All</option>
                  <% @taskids.each do |taskid| %><option value="<%= taskid %>"><%= taskid %></option><% end %> 
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="by_tasktype">
                  <option value="">All</option>
                  <% @tasktypes.each do |tasktype| %><option value="<%= tasktype %>"><%= tasktype %></option><% end %> 
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="by_hostname">
                  <option value="">All</option>
                  <% @hostnames.each do |hostname| %><option value="<%= hostname %>"><%= hostname %></option><% end %> 
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="submit"/>
            </td>
         </form> 
     </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The PHP Answer: (I also don't care for this because he generates the options).

```
<select name="test">
<?php
$options = array(1 => 'Option 1', 2 => 'Option 2', 3 => 'Option 3');
foreach ($options as $key => $value) { 
   echo '<option value="' . $key . '"' . ($key == $_GET["test"] ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '>' . $value . '</option>';
} ?>
</select>
```

I also doubt you guys need to see this, but here is some of the controller to hopefully let you guys make some sense of my mess:

```
class TaskQueuesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_task_queue, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  has_scope :by_status, :by_tasktype, :by_taskid,  :by_hostname, :by_clecid

def index
    @task_queues = apply_scopes(TaskQueue).all
    @task_queues = @task_queues.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
    @clecids = TaskQueue.uniq.pluck(:clecid).sort
    @taskids = TaskQueue.uniq.pluck(:taskid).sort
    @tasktypes = TaskQueue.uniq.pluck(:tasktype).sort
    @hostnames = TaskQueue.uniq.pluck(:hostname).reject!(&:blank?)
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well Preston according to your code I added rails code.

```
<html>
<table class= "table table-bordered"%>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Status:</th>
      <th>Clec ID:</th>
      <th>Task ID:</th>
      <th>Task Type:</th>
      <th>Hostname:</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
         <form action="/task_queues" method="GET"> 
          <td>
              <select name="by_status">
                 <option value="">All</option>
                 <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                 <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                 <option value="Failed">Failed</option>
              </select>
          </td>
          <td>
              <%= select_tag "by_clecid","<option value=\"0\">All</option>"+options_for_select(@clecids.collect {|t| [t.clecid.to_s,t.clecid]}, params[:by_clecid]  ) %>
          </td>
          <td>
              <%= select_tag "by_taskid","<option value=\"0\">All</option>"+options_for_select(@taskids.collect {|t| [t.taskid.to_s,t.taskid]}, params[:by_taskid]  ) %>
          </td>
          <td>
              <%= select_tag "by_tasktype","<option value=\"0\">All</option>"+options_for_select(@tasktypes.collect {|t| [t.tasktype.to_s,t.tasktype]}, params[:by_tasktype]  ) %>
          </td>
          <td>
              <%= select_tag "by_hostname","<option value=\"0\">All</option>"+options_for_select(@hostnames.collect {|t| [t.hostname.to_s,t.hostname]}, params[:by_hostname]  ) %>
          </td>
          <td> <input type="submit"/></td>
        </form> 
      </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Well I recommend you please to look at this example and write values on your combobox because I don't have idea about what are you trying to pass strins or integer.

```
 http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/yL6w3/1/
```

Please if the code didn't worked write what you want on the link that i send you with real values please

Answer (score 0):

Preston, I will give you a very simple example of select using rails.

Table:

```
|people|
  |id| |name| |phone
   1    ABC    13245
   2    DEF    67891
```

Controller:

```
 def index
    @people = Person.all
 end
```

View:

```
 <% form_tag :controller=>"person",:action=>"index" do %>
     <%= select_tag "people",options_for_select(@people.collect {|t| [t.name.to_s,t.id]},params[:people] ) %>
     <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
 <% end %>
```

And also if you use try to pass numbers you can use this:

```
 <% form_tag :controller=>"person",:action=>"index" do %>
     <%= select_tag "phone",options_for_select(@people.collect {|t| [t.phone.to_s,t.id]},params[:phone].to_i ) %>
     <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
 <% end %>
```

However you are using HTML code try to use this with rails code

Comment: I wasn't aware of the rails way to generate a select. However how will this help? Sorry if I'm missing the obvious but doesn't this just generate HTML code? (What I'm talking about: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)

Comment: Okey i posted another answer but please I recommend you to use a real example using values because you don't give more information and nobody can read your mind, so please use real info